# Attempting to po a firebase log event on my Xcode debug console

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, debugging, console

This is a very simple issue I'm having, but I can't find anything about how to log an event like this in my debug console.  This is what I am trying to po:

I've tried accessing the logEvent message and selectedValue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZj0R.png) anyway I could think to and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It register the message to its database, so you'd need to ask the database the last event registered. I don't know if Firebase provides a method to do so...

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, please do not include links in questions; if the link breaks future readers will have no idea what's your asking about. Ether embed the image in the question or include it textually. Secondly, the console fully supports print commands `print("some log message")` in Swift or `NSLog( @"Here is a test message: '%@'", message );` in ObjC